# Running Java based open source

Tags: java, ctakes

This is my first time to use Java, and I have no experience in Java, but good experience in .Net

I have downloaded an open source code called ctakes

and downloaded IntelliJ IDE community version

i pointed to the main folder of the project to be opened by IntelliJ IDE

but when i try to run it, it does not work

not sure what the problem is and how to fix it.

I want help in making the code runs successfully, any help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: https://ctakes.apache.org/downloads.cgi: There is a user installation guide  if you want to **use** ctakes. There is also a Developer Install guide if you want to modify the tool. You need to decide what you want to do, and read th instructions.

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CTAKES/cTAKES+4.0+Developer+Install+Guide. It looks to me you have just downloaded the source, not followed the guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about [this](https://github.com/apache/ctakes) repo, this is a maven based project. In order to import it correctly, follow [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html) link
and refer to `Open an existing Maven project` section.

A maven is a build tool that will automatically download all the dependencies required for the project source and apply them in classpath accordingly.

You might have to install maven first. You can download that from [here](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi).

Comment: Don’t see why it would be the github mirror - the project is SVN hosted. Although I suppose if the OP is more comfortable with GitHub it might be easier.

Comment: Because its an open source apache project - https://ctakes.apache.org/? and the author mentions it in the question? `I have downloaded an open source code called ctakes`

Comment: Perhaps going to their website might be more productive than posting links to the mirror is all. The project home page has documentation. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CTAKES/cTAKES+4.0+Developer+Install+Guide

Comment: i downloaded it from apache. followed the instructions but now stuck

Comment: Stuck where? as in at what step?

Comment: what is the svn location of ctakes?

Comment: In the "New Repository Location" dialog, enter the svn checkout location of cTakes.

Comment: @asmgx that’s in the guide in the getting the code section. Follow the guide word for word, especially if you are not familiar with Java or its ecosystem.

Comment: i found this https://github.com/apache/ctakes.git and this https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ctakes/trunk which one?

Comment: now getting this error  Cannot run program "svn" (in directory "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified